# Laravel Eloquent - equivalent to first() for last?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a few models such as User, Post, Comment, etc.

In the User, I have:

```
public function posts() 
{
   return $this->hasMany('Post'); 
}
```

I can get the first post via `$customer->posts()->first()`, but what if I want to get the latest Post? There is no last() as I can see.

This is further compounded by a hasManyThrough relationship (unfortunately we inherited a wacky schema):

```
public function comments() 
{
     return $this->hasManyThrough('Comment', 'Post');
}
```

If I try to do an `$this->comments()->orderBy('comments.id', 'desc')->first();` it returns a User object??

Comment: Have you tried `$this->comments()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();`?

Comment: Yeah, I get a Post object instead of a Comment. However comments() returns the appropriate comments.

Comment: @Brobin The funny thing is, when I var_dump it, it *Thinks* it's returning a Comment (the object indicated is a Comment) but the id and subsequent fields are about the Post.

Comment: @StackOverflowed show tables schema if you have such problems.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, this

```
// User model
$this->comments()->orderBy('comments.id', 'desc')->first();
```

won't return `User` model.

And to get what you asked for, simply do this:

```
$customer->posts()->latest()->first();
```

Comment: Sorry I misspoke. It was returning a Post object dressed up as a Comment. Basically it was a Comment object but all the fields related to the Post object it was joining on.

Comment: Like in my previous comment - show your tables, because it seems you have something wrong in there.

Comment: how can we re implement latest method to work with another column like updated_at or add another method that applied on another fields.